# How to sort an object dynamically

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have the following JSON object
[Capture of the console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFCCT.png)
This is created by the following code:

```
$( document ).ready( function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'DonneesGraph.php?Base='+jsvar,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( retour ) {
            // Ici le traitement des données retournées placé dans quelquechose=JSON ? appelé retour 
            
            console.log( "retour" , retour );
```

And then I have organized the data with following code which is working:

```
let newArray4 = retour.map((d) => ({ date: timeConv(d.MoyDate), measurement: +d.ProductionPV}));
let newArray6 = retour.map((d) => ({ date: timeConv(d.MoyDate), measurement: +d.EauDepart }));
let newArray7 = retour.map((d) => ({ date: timeConv(d.MoyDate), measurement: +d.EauRetour }));
```

Now I am trying to do it dynamically with the following:

```
while(i <= Lenght)
{   
if (typeof Nom[i] !== 'undefined') //Test si array présent et défini et initialisé
{
  console.log('Içi',Nom[i]);// Nom[i] is defined AND initialized
  var NomCourbe = Nom[i];
  var NomArray = 'newArray'+[i];
  var testing = 'd.EauRetour';
  console.log('Nom de la courbe',NomCourbe);
  console.log('Nom de l array',NomArray);
  console.log('Colonne',C2);
 newArray[i] = retour.map((d) => ({ date: timeConv(d.MoyDate), measurement: +Nom[i] }));
  i++;
} else 
{
    console.log('Là',i);
    i++;}
}
```

But this is not working. The console.log is showing newArray1 undefined.
I have tried different things as:

```
newArray1 = retour.map((d) => ({ date: timeConv(d.MoyDate), measurement: +testing }));
or 
NomArray = retour.map((d) => ({ date: timeConv(d.MoyDate), measurement: +testing }));
```

Why nothing works?
The objet retour looks like this :
[Console.log picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz6Q8.png)
Then the target is to get this:
[Console.log picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWBUd.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of how an object looks in the console. Instead type the JSON inside your question.

Answer (score -2):

Two solutions, depending how you went to organise the output:

```
let output = {}; //Empty Object to start with.
Object.keys(retour[0]).forEach(key => { //Walk the keys of the object.
  if(key == "MoyDate") { return; } //Skip doing the date. Cause we're gonna put the date everywhere.
  output[key] = retour.map((x) => { return {"date": timeConv(x.MoyDate) , "measurement": Number(x[key])}});
});
```

or this one:

```
let Slices = []; //start with an empty array.
Object.keys(retour[0]).forEach(key => { //Walk the keys of the object.
  if(key == "MoyDate") { return; } //Skip doing the date. Cause we're gonna put the date everywhere.
//So we want each of these results to be an object, with an id, and values.
//This line is going to be rather long and full of symbols. I suggest looking at this in a bracket-matching IDE to be able
//to keep track of all those close brackets and parentheses at the end there.
  Slices.push({ "id": key, "values" : retour.map((x) => { return {"date": timeConv(x.MoyDate) , "measurement": Number(x[key])}}) });
});
```

Comment: To make this code easier to read, please try to move the comment text to question text, as this is very hard to understand.

Comment: @KirillMcQuillin thanks but i don't understand exactly what you mean and ask me to do sorry